# OpenCV does not open videos on other computers

Tags: opencv, video-capture, windows-7-x64

I have the x64 project that works perfectly fine on my Windows 7 machine whether I run deployed version or in the Visual Studio 10. Now, I got a hand on 4 other machines with x64 Windows 7 platforms and tried to install on them, however those ones work fine except the bit of code which has to capture video always fail to load.

That bit is a typical openCV video capture bit:

```
cap = VideoCapture(file);
if (!cap.isOpened ())
{
  cerr << "I have failed!" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The file variable is generated when user chooses the file to load using file dialog it works perfectly fine on all machines if the file is, for instance, a picture, therefore that's not the reason.

Maybe the produced installer does not contain the necessary library or something like that. I really have no idea.

Cheers,
Vilius

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, As I suspected some libraries were missing in the installer package, I managed to load video files once I copied compiled OpenCV to another computer and added the path to find it.

Since many people had problems loading videos when ffmpeg was not configured, I added this library manually to the deployed software and it fixed the problem. Therefore, the problem was that Visual Studio was not adding opencv_ffmpeg241_64.dll library to the installer.

Cheers,
Vilius

Comment: I had the exact opposite problem. Some one had put an opencv_ffmpeg243_64.dll on the other computer. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If the installer packed everything correctly, you still have to take care of the **codecs** yourself.

Try to install a codec pack (K-Lite Codec Pack or something else) on those machines.

Answer (score 0):

On the other machines, have you configured OpenCV with the ffmpeg option while installing it?  Check the Cmake configuration list and print it out here if possible. 
Also, it wouldn't hurt to check if you have the respective camera drivers installed correctly for those computers if you are capturing frames directly instead of from a file.

Comment: I did not intall OpenCV on other machines at all. The CMake on the computer I'm producing software has ffmepg ticked in the configurations, but I could print it out later if you wish. Regards camera, all the computers I tested it on worked perfectly fine, only loading a video file fails.